# Creating read-only user in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I need to create a read-only user can not modify APIs, Sequences, Templates and Log configuration.

Is it possible through User Management in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently WSO2 Carbon user management framework does not provide users with a read only permission for source view. I have attached a screenshot that exhibit the permission set that need for ESB mediation developer, Since "mediation" permission does not have any further fine grained permission set, your request can not be fulfilled. This is a improvement to be done.

[image]